# Customizing Rspec generators in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm writing a Rails 3.1 engine and testing with RSpec 2. When I use `rails generate`, I get spec files generated for me automatically, which is so convenient:

```
$ rails g model Foo
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20111102042931_create_myengine_foos.rb
  create    app/models/myengine/foo.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/models/myengine/foo_spec.rb
```

However, to make the generated specs play nicely with my isolated namespace, I have to wrap the spec each time manually in a module:

```
require 'spec_helper'

module MyEngine
  describe Foo do
    it "should be round"
    ...
  end
end
```

I would love to know if there's a clean and easy way to modify the automatically generated spec 'templates' so that I don't have to wrap the spec in `Module MyEngine` each time I generate a new model or controller.

Answer (score 7):

You can copy RSpec's templates using a Rake task like:

```
namespace :spec do
  namespace :templates do
    # desc "Copy all the templates from rspec to the application directory for customization. Already existing local copies will be overwritten"
    task :copy do
      generators_lib = File.join(Gem.loaded_specs["rspec-rails"].full_gem_path, "lib/generators")
      project_templates = "#{Rails.root}/lib/templates"

      default_templates = { "rspec" => %w{controller helper integration mailer model observer scaffold view} }

      default_templates.each do |type, names|
        local_template_type_dir = File.join(project_templates, type)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p local_template_type_dir

        names.each do |name|
          dst_name = File.join(local_template_type_dir, name)
          src_name = File.join(generators_lib, type, name, "templates")
          FileUtils.cp_r src_name, dst_name
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can modify the code in `#{Rails.root}/lib/templates/rspec/model/model_spec.rb` to include the module name.

Answer (score 4):

Copy the '/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/templates/controller_spec.rb' file from the rspec-rails gem to your './lib/templates/rspec/scaffold' folder, then customize it. Obviously, if you move to a new version of rspec-rails you will want to make sure that your customized template hasn't gotten stale.

Comment: This still works as of rails 7.1 / rspec 3  (but note it needs to be in your app's lib directory (not app/lib))